# Getting this error while creating a new flutter project Error : Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org"

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and I came across this error ( Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org". ) while creating new flutter project.

I Tried "flutter doctor -v" command but it is showing everything is fine, I tried if there is any more dependencies need to be installed from given website but I couldn't find a wayand I am connected to Internet(Proxy internet) as suggested in one of the answer in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying URL of the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file. For example, instead of:

```
url_launcher: ^5.0.2
```

try this:

```
  url_launcher: 
    hosted:
      name: url_launcher
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    version: ^5.0.2
```

The official documentation shows [various ways of using packages](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Running this command fixed this issue for me,

```
flutter config --no-enable-web
```